# CMake Executable Command

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have a complex set of C++ Libraries and Python code built using CMake. When I launch the debugger from the generated project in XCode or Visual Studio, I would like to run

```
python testprogram.py
```

and automatically attach the debugger. I know I can `add_custom_target`, but this adds BUILD commands when what I want is the ability to execute the program by running a python script and hitting breakpoints in c++. Likewise, running `add_custom_command` adds additional build commands at different points.

I thought perhaps I could set a property of the custom target but I cannot find the right way to modify what program is run on launch of a target.

Comment: While you can probably make this work, this sort of thing isn't really what CMake is designed for.  Run/Debug configuration is typically a property of your IDE.  CMake does not know about all of the different editors that exist nor how to configure them for interactive running or debugging of targets.

Comment: You may be able to use [the `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND.html) target property. I haven't used that property though and it does only work for VS according to the docs...

Comment: @fabian After posting,  I did find some material on the `VS_DEBUGGER_[stuff]` type commands and this looks like it is very much what is desired. I'm still searching for options on how to deal with non-VS generators.

Comment: @0x5453 I think that may have been true traditionally, but new-ish commands like VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND indicate that VS (at least) supports this feature.